# How can I add an item to the right click menu on the desktop

Tags: c#, desktop, right-click

I have an application that runs in the background and changes the user's desktop background at set intervals. I would like to make it possible for the user to right click the desktop background and have the option to download the photo or advance to the next background, in addition to the normal windows right click options. Is there any way to do this in C#?

The target OS is Windows 8.1, but if it could work across several versions of Windows, that would be great.

Thanks to kennyzx for suggesting [Sharp Shell context menu](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus). It's a relatively easy library to understand for someone who is not use to using some of the deeper C# concepts yet.

Comment: Sounds like you need to write an extension for Windows Explorer. Usually such extensions are written in C++ so you don't load .NET into an OS process.

Comment: Google "codeproject shell context menu" and you can find some sample projects to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in a setup and deployment project. [This](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/) article shows the steps to add a menu option in the desktop context menu

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to edit registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\shell` as described here..
http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/