# Add a custom option in context menu in windows explorer background

Tags: c#, windows, contextmenu, regedit

I am trying to add a custom option to context menu in the background. The image shows the context menu I am talking about. The menu does not show up on right-click to a folder, file, or drive. It just pops up when I right click on windows explorer in the background. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HMD7.png). I am open to a solution in which i have to manually set something in regedit or a program would also do (in c#). I'm using vs2008.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308674/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-right-click-menu-on-the-desktop (can't flag possible duplicate because of no accepted answer)

Comment: No, this is only for desktop. I want to add an option in explorer background context menu